# How to use Afterburner.fx with Gradle instaed of Maven 3, while leaving the original project structure of afterburner.fx

Tags: gradle, javafx, dependency-injection, javafx-8

**afterburner.fx** for JavaFX 8 is a minimalistic (3 classes) JavaFX MVP framework based on **Convention over Configuration** and **Dependency Injection** created by Adam Bien.

afterburner.fx use Maven 3.

I would like to use it with Gradle.

How to use **Afterburner.fx** with **Gradle** instaed of Maven 3, while leaving the original project structure of afterburner.fx ?

Answer (score 4):

In the **build.gradle** File add dependencies

```
dependencies {
  compile group: 'com.airhacks', name:'afterburner.fx', version: afterburnerfxVersion
}
```

In the **build.gradle** File add the additional Resources (.fxml , .css , .properties)

```
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs("src/main/java").includes.addAll(["**/*.fxml", "**/*.css", "**/*.properties"])
```

and (re-)add all the standard Resources (in the resources folder)

```
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs("src/main/resources").includes.addAll(["**/*.*"])
```

Update for **Gradle Version 6.8.1** : if you run gradlew with --warning-mode all there is a deprecated Message:

```
Copying or archiving duplicate paths with the default duplicates strategy has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0.
```

**Solution**

add this line:

```
// from https://docs.gradle.org/6.8.1/userguide/upgrading_version_5.html#implicit_duplicate_strategy_for_copy_or_archive_tasks_has_been_deprecated
// and https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html
// Java Plugin Task processResources(type: Copy)
processResources.duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE // allow duplicates
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, this helped me a lot. I added the short form of it to dependencies:

```
compile 'com.airhacks:afterburner.fx:1.6.0'
```

Additionally I added a second line to include the files from the resources folder and not only from /java. I also added `**/*.png` to include png files because `new Image("filename.png")` wasn't working anymore.

```
sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs("src/main/java").includes.addAll(["**/*.fxml", "**/*.css", "**/*.properties", "**/*.png"])

sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs("src/main/resources").includes.addAll(["**/*.fxml", "**/*.css", "**/*.properties", "**/*.png"])
```

I don't know why the above two lines broke the default behavior - seems like I have to add every new file type to the above lines. :/ If anyone has a better solution please tell me.